# LongSparseArray в RecyclerView, сортировка

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

У меня есть список с `LongSparseArray<Object>`. Всё работает очень хорошо, по ключу обновляется Object и перерисовывается. И сейчас поставили задачу, сортировать список, по `int`, это одно из полей в `Object`. Я обычно делаю это через `Collections`, как быть с `SparseArray`? Очень хочется узнать, как вы справляетесь с такой задачей. Пробовала `HashMap`, но там мне кажется нет однозначного решения, всё сводится к перебору всех элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант завести ArrayList и заполнить его ключами из LongSparseArray. Отсортировать компаратором:

```
(o1, o2) -> return lsa.get(o1).getFooProperty().compareTo(lsa.get(o2).getFooProperty());
```

И recyclerView отстраивать по ArrayList'у, получая элементы  `lsa.get(arrayList.get(position))`...

Но разумеется возникает вопрос, учитывая, что вы пробовали с хэшмэпом, почему сразу не попробовать с ArrayList? Иными словами, откуда вы берете LongSparseArray и какая цель в его использовании, если он очевидно не подходит для задачи?